# Angular dynamically add ng-click to many elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, svg

I have an Ionic application with an SVG object with many rectangles (e.g. `<rect class="info" id="1001" width="20" height="20" transform="translate(40,40)" />`). I would like to add an `ng-click` directive to each of these without going through and manually appending `ng-click` to each of them.

Currently, instead, I have the following code in the controller:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#svg').on('click', 'rect.info', dispInfo);
}
```

This works as needed, but does not seem to be the "Angular" way. Is there a better way of doing this?

I have tried the following which seemed more angular, yet to no avail:

```
var elems = $('#svg rect.info');
elems.attr('ng-click', 'dispInfo()');
$compile(elems);
```

This successfully adds the ng-click directive to the proper elements, but they do not fire. Could it be a problem with the way I am calling `$compile` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be in more angular way, why cant to wrap your svg rectangle with a **directive** and add ng-click as part of directive template?

The problem I see with your code is, $compile function accepts html template.
You can try the below,

```
var elems = $('#svg rect.info'),
    $parent = elems.parent();

elems.attr('ng-click', 'dispInfo()');
elems = $compile(elems.html())($scope); // pass your scope variable instead of $scope
$parent.empty().append(elems);
```

Comment: Hmm, this seems to be the same as before -- no effect. When I throw in a `console.log(elems.html())` it is the empty string

Comment: I have updated my answer, but I am not sure why elems.html() returns nothing. If you can reproduce this is in jsFiddle, share it to check further.